# PHP upload and resize image

Tags: php, file-upload, autoresize

I am working on a script that uploads a picture using PHP and I wanna make it resize the image to width 180 before saving it.
I tried using the WideImage library and ->saveFileTO(...) but when I include the WideImage.php in the page, the page goes blank !!
So here is my script if you can help me and tell me how to make it save the resized version

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [PHP GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to resize an image on upload.

The following code should give you an idea of how to implement the resize:

```
// Get the image info from the photo
$image_info = getimagesize($photo);
$width = $new_width = $image_info[0];
$height = $new_height = $image_info[1];
$type = $image_info[2];

// Load the image
switch ($type)
{
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($photo);
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($photo);
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($photo);
        break;
    default:
        die('Error loading '.$photo.' - File type '.$type.' not supported');
}

// Create a new, resized image
$new_width = 180;
$new_height = $height / ($width / $new_width);
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// Save the new image over the top of the original photo
switch ($type)
{
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        imagejpeg($new_image, $photo, 100);
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
        imagegif($new_image, $photo);         
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        imagepng($new_image, $photo);
        break;
    default:
        die('Error saving image: '.$photo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class I've written for just such a task:

http://code.google.com/p/image2/source/browse/#svn/trunk/includes/classes

```
<?php

    try
    {
        $image = new Image2($path_to_image);
    }
    catch (NotAnImageException $e)
    {
        printf("FILE PROVIDED IS NOT AN IMAGE, FILE PATH: %s", $path_to_image);
    }

    $image -> resize(array("width" => 180)) -> saveToFile($new_path); // be sure to exclude the extension
    $new_file_location = $image -> getFileLocation(); // this will include the extension for future use
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to use the WideImage library.

Check this script here:
http://bgallz.org/502/php-upload-resize-image/

You start by uploading the image and saving to a temp image file. This script runs off a form with inputs for the max height or max width. So it will then generate a new image file based on the new width/height and then copy the temp image onto the new one created on the server.

You see this with the following code:

```
// Create temporary image file.
$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
// Copy the image to one with the new width and height.
imagecopyresampled($tmp,$image,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont use any library 
Check this script 
http://dr-wordpress.blogspot.com/2013/12/image-resizing-using-php.html
Just gave the quality of imges from (0-99)
this code will automatically resize the images while uploading