# How to auto resize image when upload using php

Tags: php

i want to make my image size as my given size when it upload.

my php code

```
$picture_name =time().'-' .$_FILES["picture"]["name"];
if($c->Insert())
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"], "Portfolio_Image/" . $picture_name); 
}
```

But how can i re-size image at upload time

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP upload and resize image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159897/php-upload-and-resize-image)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the PHP GD library. In particular the [imagecopyresized](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php) function. The example on there is a pretty good one.